# What is the threshold for incorrect reviews?

Tags: support, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

I've done some reviews, and suddenly, today, I failed an audit test. I'm not disputing the faliure (ok, <strike>I screwed up</strike> the system considers that I've wrongly proposed that a question should be closed), but the audit page now says:

> You have made too many incorrect reviews.[...]
>
> Come back in 2 days to continue reviewing.

What is the threshold for this? (is it public?) Do the incorrect reviews "die" as time goes by?

Note: I'm not complaining; I like people (or automated systems) to tell me when I screw up... but I'm curious about this particular rule.

Comment: _"This last post I've reviewed... I really think it's a "bad" post!"_ If you're referring to this [particular question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728192/find-kth-element-in-an-expanding-string), I can't see anything wrong with it. At least it looks it was particularly helpful for a lot of people finding the right answers there.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ok (I've removed that part of my question)... but... do you know which is the "threshold" for the review queue(s) to bump me out? that "too many incorrect reviews" observation is what makes me ask... 5? 10?

Comment: It's not a static number.  It's dependent on your history of review bans, and considers the length of time of the failed reviews.

Comment: Interesting question. I just made "too many incorrect reviews" myself, after failing a test (it was a bad question in my opinion, but I can see now why others think differently about it). The thing is: AFAIK this was the first failed test in 5 days (maybe even more). Doesn't that count for anything? Note: I too, am not here to complain. I just want to understand the rules better. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the threshold for this? (is it public?) Do the incorrect
>   reviews "die" as time goes by?

- The exact threshold isn't public, and it depends on your past audit failures.
- As you complete more reviews and audits without failing one, the tolerance increases. If you fail one immediately after your ban expires, that counts more severely then if you fail one after reviewing properly for a month.